# Curl to collect 50 device configurations

Tags: shell, curl

I am using WSL and I currently have 50 Citrix devices that I would like to download the configuration from. I have made a curl command that does one.

```
curl  -k "sftp:nsr1.sys.xxx.yyyy.zzzz:/nsconfig/ns.conf" --user "$TECHOPS_USERNAME:$TECHOPS_PASSWORD" -o "test.txt"
```

I have created a .txt called ADC.txt that will contain all 50 hosts names. What can I do so that I can loop through all 50 devices and also get the output to have the hostname of which ever device it has taken the config from? I have read up on using `xargs` but I don't get how I would combine the two.